# python - web scraping exercise

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape some some names and addresses from a random website.
This is just an academic exercise to practice my skills.

The intent of the exercise is to have a dataframe with a list of names of betting shops and corresponding addresses (or simply postcodes). Here is my code so far. However, it returns an error as the list for the names is shorter than the list for postcodes. I need to check that the first character is of the list of postcode is always a number and not import them into the list? How to do that?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get('http://www.bettingshopfinder.co.uk/location/london')
htmlpg = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
name = htmlpg.find_all('a', class_ = 'title')
address = htmlpg.find_all('p')

OutletName = []
for nm in name:
    OutletName.append(nm.find('span').get_text())

OutletAddress = []
for ad in address:

    if not isinstance(, str):    
    OutletAddress.append(ad)

Outlet = pd.DataFrame({'name':OutletName, 'Address' : OutletAddress})
```

Comment: it's not very convenient for us to help you if you change the nature of the question when we answer.

Answer (score 0):

First , you are using wrong iterator name there :

```
for nm in name:
    n = name[i]
    OutletName[i] = n.find('span').get_text()
    i += 1
```

Your iterator name is  `nm` so use `nm.find`

second you dont need to that block of code you can do just by this :

```
for nm in name:
    OutletName.append(nm.text)
```

> I need to check that the first character is of the list of postcode is
>   always a number

Just use `string library isdigit()` method:

```
OutletAddress = []
for ad in address:
    if ad.text[0].isdigit():
        OutletAddress.append(ad.text)
```

full code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get('http://www.bettingshopfinder.co.uk/location/london')
htmlpg = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
name = htmlpg.find_all('a', class_ = 'title')
address = htmlpg.find_all('p')

OutletName = []
for nm in name:
    OutletName.append(nm.find('span').get_text())

OutletAddress = []
for ad in address:
    if ad.text[0].isdigit():
        OutletAddress.append(ad.text)


Outlet = pd.DataFrame({'name':OutletName, 'Address' : OutletAddress})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.bettingshopfinder.co.uk/location/london')
htmlpg = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
name = htmlpg.find_all('a', class_ = 'title')
address = htmlpg.find_all('p')

OutletName = []
for nm in name:
    OutletName.append(nm.find('span').get_text())

OutletAddress = []
for ad in address:

    l = ad.get_text()
    if l[0].isdigit():    
        OutletAddress.append(l)

Outlet = pd.DataFrame({'name':OutletName, 'Address' : OutletAddress})
```